# How can I stop spaces from switching automatically?

Tags: leopard, spaces

I will often use Spaces on Mac OS X 10.5 to switch to another space when a program is busy / unresponsive. Very often, without warning or apparent reason, Spaces will switch *back* to the first space without my requesting it to do so. Why does it do this and how can i stop it? How can I make spaces only switch in response to my requests?

Comment: @mankoff: It does, or worse, it will do it when i am *typing something* in one app, it will switch me away from that app to a space with another app. It often happens when an app is unresponsive. Like earlier today when I asked this, iTunes couldn't find some songs and was just giving the spinning beachball. I switched spaces to write some code, and every ~5 seconds it would switch *back* to iTunes, which was still unresponsive.

Comment: I don't doubt it.  This happens to me a lot.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Stop Spaces from switching spaces due to an app coming to the foreground:

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -bool NO && killall Dock
```

Or via the GUI: `System Prefs > Spaces` and then uncheck the checkbox at the bottom: "When switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows for the application"

Stop (slow down) Spaces from switching spaces if your mouse presses against the edge of the desktop:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-edge-delay -float 60 && killall Dock
```

Comment: nice one mankoff!

Comment: That first one sounds *perfect*, but I just did it and now, when I *click* an app in the dock, the system no longer switches to that space. If it also solves the issue I was having, I can live with it however :-)

Comment: @Josh I find the first one necessary. What if I want two terminals open on different spaces? Or a new browser in the current space? Not easily possible if the spaces keep switching elsewhere...

Comment: I found that System Preferences -> Spaces -> Turn Off, was the solution to 100% of the problems spaces was giving me. I have dual screens, so “context” switching is not for me, I hide things I don’t use. But then again, I have 12GB of RAM so I understand that in small screens or more constricted environments the simplicity of having different contexts and being able to switch to them might be desirable. I’d use spaces if I could make the switch instant, as fast as a HIDE/UNHIDE works. I don’t like the swooosh thing.

Comment: @Martín hyperspaces 1.1 supports non-animated transition. Also, what if you have 5 projects each with 3 terminal windows? Hide/unhide doesn't support this workflow.

Comment: @Mankoff Let’s just say I don’t use terminal for coding, I use Xcode and/or occasionally Visual Studio for .NET inside a virtual machine. Thanks for the Hyperspaces tip, I will check it back. But I really never needed spaces. Maybe with an *instant* switch I could come up with some good ideas :)

Comment: I tried your solution and it stops switching if an app is already open, but how can I prevent the switch if an app opens in an other space. E.g. I’m on space 1 and iTunes is set to show always on space 2, if I start iTunes while working on space 1 Leopard switches to space two automatically. Is it possible to open iTunes on the second space in the “background”?

Comment: @Josh I know you've probably figured this out by now, but I'm leaving this here for posterity: To switch to the space an app is in using the Dock, you can just _double_-click it instead of single-clicking it.