# Cmd+Tab does not work on hidden or minimized windows

Tags: macos, application-switcher

When I want to switch between windows using <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> it does not work with hidden or minimized windows. I can see the icons of these windows in the application switcher but choosing them does nothing. How can I get this to work again?

Comment: I just got a Mac, and this whole minimizing shit and not being able to restore that Window from Cmd+Tab—although it is shown within the window switcher—is super illegal UX.

Comment: @Kalaschnik Totally agree

Comment: This is f. crap. I work on a mac for 8 months and I can't get used to it. Its bad user experience. I do recall some articles praising intelligent people working in Apple on the design. I don't get it why they decided like this.

Comment: Not sure how it exactly was back in 2013 but I remember Cmd+Tab working on hidden apps at least since macOS Sierra in 2016 (and possibly before that as well).

Comment: @Marecky Just use Cmd+H to hide your apps and you should be fine. Apps hidden by Cmd+M not being brought forward by Cmd+Tab is useful because it prevents the screen from being cluttered if one accidentally releases the tab key on the wrong app. It is nice to have such an option.

Comment: Apple has a habit of of prioritizing system performance and aesthetics over usability features, when the tradeoffs are significant. What is unforgivable is Apple's assumtion that users will eventually get used to their design decisions. Doesn't work in all cases. This is one glaring example. The dumb mouse is another.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

This one is a bit tricky :

- press <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> to show your running apps. Keep holding <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>.
- press <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> until you've selected the app
- press the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>, and let go of the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>. 
  ( You must release <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> **after pressing** <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> ! )
  ( You must release <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> **before release** <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> ! )

Comment: Thank you, that worked. It's not very intuitive though. Is there a reason why it is necessary to press option to get the app back?

Comment: I did not know this trick. A little difficult for the fingers.

Comment: After playing, here are some notes. Contrary to what one could think, the Option trick does not show all windows in the target application. As long as the target app has at least one non-hidden window, the Option trick does nothing. Otherwise, when the target app has one or more hidden window(s), the Option trick shows **one**, and only one, of these windows. More interesting yet : with apps like the Terminal, or the Activity Monitor, the Option trick will create a new window. **In fact, Apple Tab with the Option trick is the equivalent of clicking the target app in the Dock.**

Comment: Is there a way to make it "opposite"?

Comment: would be nice if osx could be configured to behave properly here ... osx is falling behind linux more every day

Comment: This, along with hotkeys for Print Screen and Chrome history, gives me the Mac-migraine.

Comment: This is great but command tab should do this!!

Comment: @MattCanty try `⌘ Cmd` + `y` for Chrome history and `⌘ Cmd` + `Shift` + `4` for screenshot (then, select with mouse drag&drop which part of the screen you want to save as an image)

Comment: You don't need to release `⌘ Cmd` after pressing `⌥ Option` in step 3, if you use mouse click on app icon.

Comment: Stills works 2022

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco
It is showing the last used one. If you minimise a window and use this trick, it will pop the last used window
but it doesn't do that when you click a different app and hide the other on-screen window, this seems to make the on-screen window the last used.
But he is 100% right it is exactly the same behaviour as clicking in the dock.
Clicking the dock is the same expected behaviour as CMD-TAB, but Apple in their wisdom chose not to, for some reason.
APPLE SORT IT OUT!

Comment: Alternatively at step-3 hit the up cursor and the (multiple) minimised windows will be shown in thumbnail and you can tab/enter the one you want back to life

Comment: What a bizarre user-interface show the app, but make it such that alt-tab doesn't focus it without a weird incantation that no one knows.

Comment: "think different"

Comment: @Stefan Thank you - very helpful. This does not bring up application that are in full screen. Do you know how to focus them without three finger swipe?

Comment: @QuaziIrfan I think it's not possible because macOS make that window like separate virtual screen

Answer (score 61):

**Majority of the answers are years old. This is a 2021 solution**

Use [AltTab](https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/), it is the exact replica of windows functionality of Alt+ Tab. Takes care of both minimised/maximised window.

It's free and open source.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! `brew install alt-tab --cask`

Comment: It didn't make a difference here :/

Comment: It defaults to a different keyboard shortcut, but you can choose your own to fit your muscle memory.

Comment: Been checking back every year for a "real solution" and seems 2021 is my lucky year. So exciting! Works, and you can disable the thumbnails so it looks more likely the regular version. This is now the correct answer.

Comment: Heads up: I was expecting it to take over the default `alt + tab` behavior (and thought it wasn't working when that didn't happen) but discovered you need to change the app's Controls preferences slightly to get that effect.

Comment: This is so perfect, its snappy, fast, and very customizable. Great solution to such a flawed UX, the default behaviour is under the `option + tab`

Comment: Awesome app! But I have concerns regarding the permission to record the screen. Did anyone check the source code for malicious intents?

Comment: @KirillKarmazin yes same, I held off installing this while it needs that permission

Comment: Wow, this works amazingly well.  Just open preferences and reassign alt-tab to cmd-tab to seamlessly override MacOS default switching.  Thanks!!

Comment: It's not the *exact replica*. It does not take virtual desktops into account.

Comment: I've been forced to use a Mac after decades of linux. This app has been extremely helpful in alleviating a bit the absolutely disgusting abject horror. Thank you. Thank you so much.

Comment: OMG thank you! This is perfect.

Comment: This one should be the standard behavior and the correct answer to this post. Awesome tip and app! Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thank god this software exists. It's the only thing that makes alt-tab in macOS usable.

Answer (score 58):

Use <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle to the desired application and then, while still holding down <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>, press the <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> arrow. This will show the application's windows in Expose. Select the desired window with the arrow keys and press <kbd>Return</kbd> to activate it.

http://www.macworld.com/article/1152366/commandtabminimizedwindows.html

Comment: Found this more recent article useful and on point for this question.  http://www.macworld.com/article/2048857/10-tips-for-managing-minimized-windows.html

Comment: this is true however I fail to see the benefit of apple's approach to not auto show a minimized app's window when the app is selected using command+tab ... linux window managers just do what's most natural ... time to short apple stock

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me for either hidden or minimised windows. I always get "No Available Windows". I'm on Sierra if it makes any difference.

Comment: Pretty nice in combo with left/right arrows after you hit Ctrl+Tab too. Arrows all the way to the window you're seeking.

Comment: This worked for me for ~8 years but suddenly stopped working today. Now I need to use this awkward approach: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/112358/70049

Answer (score 23):

Press <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to hide a window instead of minimising it.

Comment: This is great, yet (on Catalina anyways) as a caveat, it looks like once you hide the windows, they can't be found with the up-arrow after cmd-tab mentioned in another answer. So odd that cmd-M and cmd-H both make the window hide in a completely different way, and are restored in completely different ways!

Comment: I like this solution best.  I just have to get in the habit of using command h to hide any windows I don't want up on the screen instead of minimizing them. Too bad there is not a mouse way of doing the Hide... the yellow button only does minimize.

Comment: Note that %-H is a toggle: press once to Hide a window, press again to un-Hide it. Also note that it doesn't work on Maximized windows.

Comment: Holy shit, hiding and minimizing, the same visual thing happens, but different behavior. Suck it.

Comment: Just a footnote - This has implications on the way system resources are utilized. Cmd-H is costlier if you have scores of applications opened but not all of them are actively used.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

On your Mac,

1. Navigate to System Preferences
2. Go to Mission Control
3. Uncheck "When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application"

Try using the <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> now.

Comment: this works only for  not minized windows

Comment: This does nothing for me.

Comment: I was SO hoping this was the answer, but no.

Comment: FINALLY!!! After years, this is the fix! Big big thanks!

Answer (score 2):

HyperSwitch Does the trick : 
https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch

I tested it. It needs to be updated. It's free. When I Cmd+Tab on minimized app it's open!

Comment: I just looked at the hyperswitch website and one of their "Known issues" is "No option to show minimized windows yet." ... ? I haven't actually tried it though!

Comment: On that linked page it says in big letters, known issues, "No option to show minimized windows yet." Aka it doesn't do the one thing people are asking for here.  Luckily the other answer AltTab does.

Answer (score 2):

So a summary of answers in other comments here;

### Change the way you "Command-Tab"

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to an app, and before releasing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>, also hold down <kbd>Opt</kbd>. This will open minimized apps like expected, but is annoying to remember to do.

### Install a replacement for <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

`brew install --cask alt-tab` and use that instead. Should behave more like Windows 10/11, but you have to break the habit of hitting <kbd>Cmd</kbd> or use a key remapper to swap them.

### Change the way you *close* apps

Use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to hide apps rather than <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. Now opening them with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> should work as expected for those apps. This is what you probably *should* be doing, if your workflow is to hide things out of sight, then open them again later, e.g. MS Teams, Outlook, Calendar, etc., things that you still want to get notifications from, but don't need in front of you.

Personally, I love my <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, so it's a hard habit to break to remember to only hide my Calendar/Slack, etc rather than just killing them.

Answer (score 2):

A 2023 answer I'm using a different solution.

If you turn on Stage Manager then apps both hide and minimise into Stage Manager. Then when you <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> windows will come back for you whether they were hidden, minimised, or just moved away from.

This is on Ventura.

It's important to note that this only works on things you minimise or hide **after** you enable Stage Manager. And you can turn off Stage Manager's app drawer thing as well if you want.

I can't install AltTab unfortunately, so glad to have found this option.

Comment: That is so random of Apple to have one feature magically change when the other is activated. But I shouldn't be surprised with the amount of bugs and bad UX I've encountered in just a couple days of using macOS..

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the MC view. Anyway Keyboard Maestro provides with a simple keyboard customizable shortcut, a very good app launcher, very similar to cmd-tab/alt-tab universal function, but more customizable and with more options inside. You can browse through the apps in sliding with trackpad or mouse. Left click on icons open a menu. You can open from that menu or hit enter key. In that sliding view there are many apps; hidden, minimized, opened, and recent.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why unclear, it is another way to activate an effective app switcher with cmd+tab, including hidden and minimized windows and more, as from title of topic.

Answer (score 0):

My symptoms..
<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> would toggle the heading bar for each application but only some windows for the application would show up.

The suggestion above:
On your Mac,

*Navigate to System Preferences
Go to Mission Control
Uncheck "When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application"
Try using the <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>  now.*

Was already in place on my Mac. I did the opposite and now <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>  works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Like Pirate X mentioned. Alt+Tab works flawlessly. You can even set the key to be Command instead of Option (Alt) and have it work normally but being able to raise minimized windows without having to press alt on the selected window.

It's super easy to install if you have "homebrew" installed:

```
brew install --cask alt-tab
```

Or just go to their website: https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app and download it for manual installation.

Comment: I don't suggest alt-tab bcs it is breaking something on every update. Developer doesn't test it correctly and he doesn't care bug reports.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a more convenient alternative to the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> solution:
after switched to the desired app and released the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> press <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

goto settings->Desktop & Dock

make sure that below options are enabled.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

AppleScript

```
tell application "Slack" to reopen (activate)
```

Or try my app [Command-Tab Plus](http://commandtab.noteifyapp.com), in addition to proper  work with hidden or minimized apps has many convenient features that are not efficiently implemented in the built-in MacOs App's switcher

For example, there were discussed the problems of Mac Os X apps switcher

[Restricting Command+tab options to only apps that are in the current space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5668/restricting-commandtab-options-to-only-apps-that-are-in-the-current-space)

Show only apps that are in the current space