# How can I disable window auto-focus?

Tags: window-manager, spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stop spaces from switching automatically?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4801/how-can-i-stop-spaces-from-switching-automatically)

Is there any way to disable the "feature" wherby when I'm in one virtual desktop and something happens in a window in another virtual desktop, OS X automatically switches to it?

Comment: It appears that you are asking the same question that was already answered in [this post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4801/how-can-i-stop-spaces-from-switching-automatically). We try to avoid duplicating answers here, but if this does not answer your question, please edit your question to explain the difference and flag it so we can reopen the question.